# Creating your own events JavaFX

Tags: java, events, javafx

I have 2 classes, for example A and B. In class A, I have a `modal` field with type `Stage`. 
It awards tracking window close events `modal.setOnCloseRequest(this::closeWindow);` and a method reference. In class B, I run a window close event `listeners.stream().ForEach(l -> l.handle(new WindowEvent(owner.getShape().GetScene().GetWindow(),WindowEvent.WINDOW_CLOSE_REQUEST)));` and the desired window closes. Now I need to create my own event, which instead of `Window` in WindowEvent would pass an object of type `Object`, and class A would be able to track this event. I just started working with events in Java.

My event to track

```
public class CloseWindowEvent extends Event {

private Object object;

public CloseWindowEvent(EventType<? extends Event> eventType, Object object) {
    super(eventType);
    this.object = object;
}

    public Object getObject() {
        return object;
    }
}
```

How can I trigger my CloseWindowEvent event in class B and make an event handler in class A?

Comment: You’ve described your situation, but I don’t see a question here.

Comment: How can I trigger my CloseWindowEvent event in class B and make an event handler in class A? Added to the main question.

Comment: Perhaps a [mcve] showing what you want to happen would be helpful.

Comment: the eternal question: why? Sounds like a xy-problem to me ...